# local variable referenced before assignment in strange condition

Tags: mysql, eclipse, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have some code that takes input from an open source database, then returns a report based on some of the tables. I could have sworn that this code was working correctly yesterday, but when I boot it up today:

```
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\whicaso1\Downloads\eclipse-standard-luna-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.6.0.201406232321\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1845, in 
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Users\whicaso1\Downloads\eclipse-standard-luna-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.6.0.201406232321\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1373, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Users\whicaso1\workspace\Status based chilli list\CreateChiliLog.py", line 29, in 
    CreateChiliLog()
  File "C:\Users\whicaso1\workspace\Status based chilli list\CreateChiliLog.py", line 15, in CreateChiliLog
    for chili in chili_database.getChilis(status):
  File "C:\Users\whicaso1\workspace\Status based chilli list\ChiliFunctions.py", line 99, in getChilis
    connection_chili.rollback()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'connection_chili' referenced before assignment
```

Now, I'm not a moron, I checked to see if I had, in fact, referenced the variable "connection_chili" before assignment, but it looks like the error occurred *while* assigning. (here is the code snippet that failed, the error is on the line where the connection_chili variable is being assigned to a mysqldb database object.)

```
 
def getChilis(self, status):
        try:
            connection_chili = MySQLdb.connect(self.host_, self.user_, self.password_, self.database_)
            cursor = connection_chili.cursor()
            query = "SELECT id FROM issues WHERE status_id = %i" % status
            cursor.execute(query)
            connection_chili.commit()
            chilis = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.close()
            return chilis
```

```
    except Exception, e:
        connection_chili.rollback()
        print "ERROR: " + str(e)
```

is there some issue with my code, or is there some weird thing going on with my python compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked my code against python in cmd, and it ran fine.  So I'm guessing its probably some weird issue with eclipse.  In any case, its no longer a programming question, so I'm going to close it